# Filter columns in where clause based on the passed argument?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, where-clause

I have query that has to be filtered based on the argument passed in the function. This will decide if I will pull records based on the `Name`, `Code` or pull `All` records. Here is example of the query:

```
DECLARE @FilterBy INTEGER = <cfqueryparam value="#trim(arguments.frm_filterby)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" />;

SELECT RecID, Status, Code, Name
FROM Dictionary WITH (NOLOCK)       
WHERE 
    (@FilterBy = 1 AND Name LIKE <cfqueryparam value="#trim(arguments.frm_search)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="50" />)
    OR 
    (@FilterBy = 2 AND Code = <cfqueryparam value="#trim(arguments.frm_search)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_char" maxlength="2" />)
    OR 
    (@FilterBy = 3 AND 1 = 1)
ORDER BY Name
```

As you can see I declare variable for filter and set that as integer and then I use `OR` to filter columns. I'm wondering if this is good approach for this kind of situation or there is better way to do this? Is there a way to do this with `CASE` statement?

Comment: Looks fine.(It's generally a good idea to avoid `case` expressions in WHERE and ON clauses.)

Comment: Your method is fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty good approach for catch-all queries.

However, catch-all queries usually have problems with performance, due to the the fact SQL Server will cache the first query plan it's created for the query, and it's probably not the best query plan for other parameters value.

In this case, the optimized query plan for `@FilterBy = 1` might be very different from the optimized query plan for `@FilterBy = 2` or `@FilterBy = 3`.

Basically, you would be better off writing a different procedure for each search. (Though admittedly that's not always a valid option - suppose you have not 3 search options but 16 columns to search, one for each variable, while everything else in the query is the same...)

Gail Shaw wrote about it on [Sql In the wild](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/), and Aaron Bertrand wrote about it, referring to this type of queries as the ["Kitchen Sink" procedure.](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example/)

Also, your query use the `NOLOCK` query hint, which is usually a sign of bad design. 
Once again, Aaron Bertrand wrote about this - [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) - It's not only dirty reads you should worry about.

One last thing, your last condition is `(@FilterBy = 3 AND 1 = 1)` - of course, the `AND 1 = 1` is completely redundant.

Comment: I read articles that you share but still I'm not sure that I have an answer on what is the best approach to prevent cache of the query in SQL. Also I notice that my solution has one flow. If I select search criteria by the Name (FilterBy is 1) I'm getting an error that parameter exceeds limit 2. That should not be the case since I'm searching the Name column. Do you know why that is happening ?

Comment: I know nothing about coldfusion, so I'm not sure how the cfqueryparam are interpated by SQL Server. Perhaps you need to wrap them with `'` (they are strings, after all)...

Comment: Single quote wrap what? Everything works so far but that one case when I select name and enter more than 2 characters.

Comment: since you are using `like` I assume that the name is a string - char/varchar/nchar/nvarchar - so the syntax is `stringColumn LIKE '%Value%'` (where `%` is an optional wildcard for 0 or more chars)

Comment: This is what I have: `DECLARE @FilterBy INT = <cfqueryparam value="#targuments.frm_filterby#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" />;
DECLARE @SearchName VARCHAR(50) = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.frm_search#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="50" />;
DECLARE @SearchCode CHAR(2) = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.frm_search#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_char" maxlength="2" />;
SELECT Code, Name FROM Dictionary
WHERE @FilterBy = 1 AND Name LIKE '%'+@SearchName+'%' OR @FilterBy = 2 AND Code = @SearchCode` still getting an error parameter exceeds max-length 2.